# With imagemagick (or OpenCV) how do I extract the hue channel to B&W

Tags: opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I would like to use segmentation techniques on an image based on hue - in one critical area of the images I want to separate I know the background has hue = 0, while the item I want to separate has hue <> 0.

How do I extract the hue channel to B&W so I can see and then use the hue changes? that is - output an B&W image where hue = 0 is black, and hue 360 is white (yes I know hue is circular)?

My general goal is to eliminate a white background behind a white shoe - or separate the shoe silhouette out.

Imagemagick is the preferred tool, but OpenCV/Python will be ok too. I'm also happy with suggestions saying I'm going down the wrong path altogether

Comment: Not sure how you could hope to separate a white shoe from a white background using hue - do you have a sample image please so we can see what you mean?

Comment: https://m-en.zalando.de/nike-sportswear-air-max-90-trainers-ni112o0bt-a11.html

The side view is a good example. Just the result of a quick search. Can’t share the actual picture. Re hue: the background is quite rigorously white - whereas the shoe will never be an absolute white

Comment: I'm sure you've found `cvtColor` so what is the goal of the question? I also find using *hue* to segment *value* (brightness) changes to be questionable. the shoe is also white, so anything that isn't *exactly* white is just noise, because it's very close to white. same goes for saturation. the whole picture will have low saturation.

Comment: The OpenCV way would be to use [cvtColor](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) to convert to HSV and then [split](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga0547c7fed86152d7e9d0096029c8518a) to get the H channel. The H channel would then be grayscale. If you truly want B & W, then you'd have to also do a threshold operation.